# Django channels. How to select consumer when sending through channel layer?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

In my application, I got two consumers with same handler names:

```py
class GeneralConsumer(AuthenticatedOnlyAsyncConsumer):
    async def new_message(self, data):
        ...

    async def message_update(self, data):
        ...

    async def message_delete(self, data):
        ...


class ChatVisitorConsumer(AuthenticatedOnlyAsyncConsumer):
    async def new_message(self, data):
        ...

    async def message_update(self, data):
        ...

    async def message_delete(self, data):
        ...
```

Consumers share same functionality, but used in different cases.

---

I wonder, how I can pick specific consumer handler in channel layer object to use `.send` or `.group_send`, obtained from function `channels.layers.get_channel_layer`.

Comment: I think you should add the consumer types to individual groups, so `GeneralConsumer` could join group `general-consumer` and `ChatVisitorConsumer` could join `chat-visitor-consumer`. If both consumers should be able to communicate with each other then add both to group `authenticated-only-consumer`. With that in place you can now pass the group name to `group_send` to invoke the functionality as required.